# Ubuntu 18.04 and Timeshift - what happens if I reboot while timeshift is taking a snapshot

Tags: filesystem, backup, system, rsync

I have Timeshift scheduled to take a snapshot at regular intervals using rsync.  What happens if I reboot during snapshot, will the incomplete snapshot be corrupt, will it be deleted, will it re-commence when I reboot.  Also is it OK to delete the initial and earlier snapshots, are they incremental or is each one complete.  I want to be sure I have reliable restore points but not too many. Thanks guys.

Comment: Thanks! Favour returned!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using TimeShift in `rsync` mode means that `rsync` is the underlying technology and it will just continue where it left off since the last warm reboot.

If you use a hard reboot (hold power button until power off) all bets are off as it now depends on your cache, exact file system (FS) used, journaling capability of the FS, ... *and the results are unpredictable*.

Comment: thanks, just waiting ton see any other answers and investigate further before I accept answer - thanks again

Comment: Just don't forget to accept if this answer helps you!  **;-)**